# Searching for slide animation like in spotify app

Tags: android, spotify, parallax

i want to find out how the animation to slide the listview up like in the app spotify is called.

[image]
[image]

So i am searching for something to pull upwards so that the picture will go ahead like in spotify. I want to insert it in a fragment which is part of a viewpager. The viewpager is part of a navigation drawer. So the target fragment is a nested one.

Thanks for your advice!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

https://github.com/ManuelPeinado/FadingActionBar

https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.manuelpeinado.fadingactionbar.demo&rdid=com.manuelpeinado.fadingactionbar.demo

#### Update

here is a collection of pupular AndroidViews

//Offline: http://www.androidviews.net

http://www.appance.com/category/android

https://android-arsenal.com/

Comment: Hm, no... this is quite a navigation drawer. I am looking for this sliding action. You can push the listview up, so that the picture supressed.

Comment: just a moment i will install spotify ^^

Comment: this ist just a scrollview.. problem u cant put a listview in a scrollview.. so u have to form your own list-elements 
//btw .. du kannst deutsch schätze ich mal =)

Comment: //noch etwas verständnisschwierigkeiten .. meinst du dass alles mitscrollt (oder ist bei mir der fall.. dass das album-cover nach unten wandert?)

Comment: Hab ich etwa typisch deutsche Fehler gemacht? Also das Bild wird leicht nach oben gedrückt und dann nach einem bestimmten Punkt wird die listview Überschrift darüber geschoben

Comment: now i see what u mean .. the image is in the background and has a different scroll speed.. interessting.. 
//ne quatsch hab nur gesehn dass die app auf deutsch ist.. dazu noch cro.. sorry stand auf der leitung.. jetzt seh ich was du meinst

Comment: Yes right... Different scrollspeed... You think i should try to use scrollview?

Comment: Perfect. That ist what i am Looping for. Thank you.

Comment: no problem.. 
//allg. würde ich es als parallax scrolling definieren.. falls du weiteres solches suchst.. hier ist noch ein link.. kannst du sicherlich auch benutzen oder die klassen übernehmen.. um es für dich anzupassen.. aber 1zu1 ist das obere nachtürlich perfekt..  https://github.com/chrisjenx/ParallaxScrollView   
ps danke fürs rating ..